# Way to see if whole canvas has been painted in one color. Javascript + processing.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, processing.js

I'm still a beginner at javascript, and I'm making a game about dying the whole screen white while the paint brush becomes smaller and smaller until in completely disappears.

I wanted to know, is there a simple way to figure out if the whole canvas has been painted, so I can put a winning screen?
I'm using the processing.js library, here is my code, if it's of any use:

```
background(255,0,0);
           var eight = 100;
           var draw = function(){
               strokeWeight(eight);
               point(mouseX,mouseY);
               eight -= 0.2;
               if(eight<0){
                   noStroke();
               }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here's a modestly efficient way of determining if the user has whited every pixel**

1. Create an array where each canvas pixel is represented by an array element.

   ```
   var pixels=new Array(canvas.width*canvas.height);
   ```
2. Initially fill the array with all zeros.
3. Create a variable that hold the # of unique pixels whited out so far.

   ```
   var whited=0;
   ```
4. When the user passes over a pixel, see if the pixel has already been whited. If it hasn't been whited, change its array value to 1 and increment the whited variable.

   ```
   var n = mouseY * canvas.width + mouseX

   if(pixels[n]=0){
       pixels[n]=1;
       whited++;
   }
   ```
5. You have a winner if the value of whited equals the number of pixels on the canvas.

   ```
   if(whited==pixels.length){
       alert('You have won!');
   }
   ```

*A thought:* Instead of making the user find every (tiny) missed pixel, you might consider making a grid so the user has an easier time finding that 1 (larger) missed grid cell instead of finding one missed pixel in a sea of white.

Comment: good efficiency since you don't have to loop over every pixel while the game isn't ended.

Answer (score 0):

You can go over all the pixels and check if they are not white

```
for (var i=0;i<imgData.data.length;i+=4)
{
if(imgData.data[i]==0&&imgData.data[i+1]==0&&imgData.data[i+2]==0&&imgData.data[i]+3==0){alert("white pixel")}
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_getimagedata.asp

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Processing, just walk over the pixels:

```
void setup() {
  ...
}

void draw() {
  ...
}

void yourCheckFunction() {
  loadPixels();
  boolean allWhite = true;
  for(int c: pixels) {
    if(brightness(c) < 255) {
      // we found a not-white pixel!
      allWhite = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (allWhite) {
    // the paint surface is entirely white.
  } else {
    // there are non-white patches left
  }
}
```

There are lots of ways to optimize this (like chopping up the surface into distinct areas with their own administrative true/false value so you can first check if they were all-white on a previous run, and if so, you don't need to recheck them) but this covers the basics:

1. assume the canvas is all white pixels
2. try to invalidate that assumption by finding a not-white pixel
3. immediately stop checking if you do
4. if there are none, your loop will end "naturally"

Alternatively, you can track how many pixels your user's action have painted. Once that number of pixels is equal to `width*height`, all pixels must necessarily be white (see markE's answer for that)